# Windows 10 Application does not load on Visual Studio 2015 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I was working on my Windows 10 project in Visual Studio 2015 RC. After upgrading to VS 2015 RTM it finds the project incompatible. I've installed Windows 10 sdk 10158.

I'm not able to create a new Windows 10 project either (kind of obvious).

I should be missing something here. Any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. [Microsoft told that the Visual Studio 2015 RTM is incompatible with the older SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads/windows-10-developer-tools). You have to wait until 29th July 2015 to get the Windows 10 RTM SDK.

> **Important:** **Do not install Visual Studio 2015 RTM until 7/29 if you
>   want to continue working with Windows 10 developer tool preview
>   releases.** On 7/29 the RTM releases of Windows 10 developer tools will
>   be made available for use with Visual Studio 2015 RTM. Please refer to
>   the Building Apps blog for more details.

I [found the link to the Webinstaller to the 10240 SDK](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/F/E1F1E61E-F3C6-4420-A916-FB7C47FBC89E/standalonesdk/sdksetup.exe) and the [Windows 10 Developer Tools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/1/4011ECDA-7484-4CEA-A53E-6C73A32A6793/Windows_VSTools.exe). Try it and be one of the first developers who can submit it's RTM app.